# Looping Buttons in tkinter and function assignment

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

i have been able to generate Buttons in tkinter using this code

```
for i in range(0, num_sheets):
            an_sheet = ttk.Button(self, text = "%s" % sh_names[i], command = partial(load_sheets))
            an_sheet.grid(row = 1, column = i+1, sticky='w', pady = 10, padx = 10)
```

now these buttons have been generated based on the number of sheets in an excel sheet and have also been assigned the names of the sheets they represent. However, there's a function to print the contents of each sheet represented.

```
def load_sheets():
            for i,sheetname in enumerate(sh_names) :
                xl_sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sh_names[i])
                print()
                print(sheetname)
                row = xl_sheet.row(0)   
                for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(row):
                    cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')

                row = xl_sheet.nrows
                for col_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.ncols):
                    print ('Column: %s' % col_idx)
                    for row_idx in range(0, row):
                        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)
                        print ('Row: [%s] cell_obj: [%s]' % (row_idx, cell_obj))
```

now the challenge is to bind the function to the button such that it prints out it's own content when it's clicked. For example, when a button named 'sheet 1' is clicked, the contents of sheet 1 should be printed.

here's the full structure of the code.

```
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        fname = join(dirname(dirname(abspath('C:/Users/qanda/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts/PEN'))), 'Python Scripts/PEN', 'Book1.xlsx')   
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
        sh_names = wb.sheet_names()
        num_sheets = len(sh_names)

        def load_sheets():
            for i,sheetname in enumerate(sh_names) :
                xl_sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sh_names[i])
                print()
                print(sheetname)
                row = xl_sheet.row(0)   
                for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(row):
                    cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')

                row = xl_sheet.nrows
                for col_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.ncols):
                    print ('Column: %s' % col_idx)
                    for row_idx in range(0, row):
                        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)
                        print ('Row: [%s] cell_obj: [%s]' % (row_idx, cell_obj))


        for i in range(0, num_sheets):
            an_sheet = ttk.Button(self, text = "%s" % sh_names[i], command = partial(load_sheets))
            an_sheet.grid(row = 1, column = i+1, sticky='w', pady = 10, padx = 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function to print the contents of one sheet, taking the sheet number as an argument. Then, use functools.partial to associate a command with each button:

```
def print_sheet(sheet_number):
    ...

for i in range(0, num_sheets):
    an_sheet = ttk.Button(..., command = partial(print_sheet, i))
    ...
```

Here's a short but complete example of creating buttons in a loop:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

root = tk.Tk()

def print_sheet(i):
    print("printing sheet %d" % i)

for i in range(0, 5):
    button = ttk.Button(root, text="Button %d" % i,
                        command=partial(print_sheet, i))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is functools.partial? It sounds very useful

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: I assumed you knew, since the code you posted is using it. At least, I'm assuming that when you used `partial` in your code, you were using `functools.partial`, even though you were using it incorrectly. If you don't know what it does, look it up.

Comment: @BryanOakley, i already know about partial, however, i tried your suggestion but it didn't work, it assigned the file location of the last sheet to all the buttons instead. so when the buttons are clicked the print out the file location of the last sheet.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: the word `partial` is indeed in your code: `command = partial(load_sheets)`. As for it not working, I can assure you it works when used like in my answer. I've updated my answer to include a complete example so you can see how it works.

Comment: nice, i just tried it, and it worked.. Thank you @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking about how to iterate through a set of functions and assign them?

You could use a dictionary

Example from my A-level computing coursework

```
self.screen_info = {"Email Customer":  {"button_names": ["Enter Email"],         "commands": [self.email_from_email]},
                    "Text Customer":   {"button_names": ["Enter Number"],        "commands": [self.text_from_number]},
                    "Backup Database": {"button_names": ["Choose Location"],     "commands": [backup_database.backup]},
                    "Export Database": {"button_names": ["As .txt", "As .csv"],  "commands": [lambda: export.main("txt"), lambda: export.main("csv")]}}


def populate(self):
    for key in self.screen_info.keys():

        self.screen_info[key]["parent"] = tk.Frame(self.screens, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "#E6E6FA")
        self.screen_info[key]["parent"].place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = tk.CENTER)

        for num in range(len(self.screen_info[key]["button_names"])):
            self.screen_info[key]["button_names"][num] = tk.Button(self.screen_info[key]["parent"],
                                                                   width = 20,
                                                                   text = self.screen_info[key]["button_names"][num],
                                                                   font = ("Ariel", 11, "bold"),
                                                                   command = self.screen_info[key]["commands"][num])
            self.screen_info[key]["button_names"][num].place(relx = 0.5, y = 60 + num * 40, anchor = tk.CENTER)
```

So this will iterate through the dictionary creating everything and assign commands. I used lambda for 'Export Database' as the function requires a parameter and if i didn't use lambda then the function would run as soon as the program was launched

**EDIT** I overwrite each key-value in the dictionary with the associated widget but if you are not referring to them again you don't even need to set a variable, key to them